# Can not write to file with android studio in my ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, file, file-io, ubuntu-18.04

I am working on android studio in my ubuntu 18.04.
I have a byte array of image. I am just trying to save it in my pc as .jpeg

```
public void SavePhotoTask(byte [] jpeg){
        File photo= new File( "desktopWallpaper.jpg");
        if (!photo.exists()) {
            try {
                photo.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            fos.write(jpeg);
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("------ error saving file" + e);
        }
    }
```

But getting this error

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.ipfs.MainActivity.SavePhotoTask(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.ipfs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/System.out: ------ error saving filejava.io.FileNotFoundException: desktopWallpaper.jpg: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Currently i just want to save it on my ubuntu storage.

Comment: `I am just trying to save it in my pc as .jpeg` Really? I would think you would make an Android app. And that app would save to a storage location on your Android device.

Comment: `Currently i just want to save it on my ubuntu storage.` That is impossible. Android apps on an Android phone have no access to pc's. Be it Windows or Linux. Be it yours be it mines.

Comment: Can i save it on my `src/main/res` folder?

Comment: Where is that folder?

Comment: This is the project directory, https://i.imgur.com/dtJlqK7.png

Comment: And where is that project directory? And which folder exactly? And what is its full path?

Comment: @blackapps this is the standard android studio project directory structure. Obviously in my pc, https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectFiles

Comment: `Obviously in my pc,` Well... if you know that then why do you try? Further there is nothing in your code that refers to a directory.... or to that directory... You should realise that you can be in town with your phone. Not in your home where your pc.